# Swim cap for men's long hair

Tags: swimming

I've been growing my hair out to donate it to either "Locks of Love" or "Pantene Beautiful Lengths".  I'd like to start "re-learning" how to swim so that I can take part in a sprint triathlon next year, but feel as though I'll need a swim cap.  Does anyone have any good recommendations?  I'm new to this type of equipment.

Thanks,
Larry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swim Outlet has a nice [discussion on swim caps](http://www.swimoutlet.com/guides/how-to-choose-a-swim-cap).  Different swim cap materials for swimming include: latex, silicon or neoprene. For water jogging or water aerobics where your face and head are not necessarily in the water, they suggest that a lycra cap is cooler.

For medium or long hair they recommend:

> If you have medium to long hair, then a silicone cap will suit you best. Silicone caps outlast their latex counterpart, are more tear resistant, and don't tug at your hair. Typically softer to the touch, a silicone cap is gentler on the hair and easier to get on and off after a workout.

For open water swims, they suggest bright colors to help make you more visible.  They also suggest that neoprene and silicone caps give more "insulation and floatation".

If you have any sensitivity or are allergic to latex, be sure to opt for an alternate material.

Answer (score 2):

My girlfriend has long hair as well. She is using just regular swimming cap and she usually do something like a bun with her hair.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bun_%28hairstyle%29

If you are not a male lion, you should be ok with a regular swimming cap. You just need to use something to tight your hair to be able to put it under your cap comfortably.

Comment: not long enough for the bun yet, but i'm a bit of a hairy guy.  i've seen caps designed for such things, but want to get more opinions.  thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

As a former competitive swimmer (and frequent swimmer now) with very long hair, I've always been partial to silicone caps. They tend to do less pulling and damage to the hair and are easier to manage.

If you want to go the extra length (no pun intended) to nourish your hair, try putting a little protective or fortifying conditioner in your hair before putting your cap on.